# "Mandelbrot sets" for different polynomials

Tags: terminology, dynamical-systems, fractals

What is the correct term for a set defined analogously to the [*Mandelbrot set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set), but for different $1$-parametric polynomial families?

I've found [*multibrot sets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multibrot_set), but they are still defined only for specific families.

Comment: I don't think they have a name, in the sources I found they are just called 'generalized Mandelbrot sets" if anything

Comment: The general term is the [bifurcation locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_locus).

Comment: So, are you asking when the family of iterates is a normal family?  That is what is interesting in complex analysis.

Answer (score 2):

[the connectedness locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectedness_locus) is a subset of the parameter space of rational functions, which consists of those parameters for which the corresponding Julia set is connected. [A bifurcation locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifurcation_locus) is the boundary of the Mandelbrot set.